# What is the difference between IIFE and function expresstion?

Tags: javascript

I get confuse about function while doing study javascript.
I think that's same thing about function.
What the difference?

```
var getCode = function() {
  apiCode = '0]Eal(eh&2';    

  return function() {
    return apiCode;
  };
}


var getCode = (function() {
  apiCode = '0]Eal(eh&2';    

  return function() {
    return apiCode;
  };
}();
```

Comment: one creates a function, other creates and *executes* a function. So the first will just result in a function assigned to `getCode` the other will have the return value of the function assigned to it (which happens to be another function in this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same difference as between `f` and `f()`. The former is a function (assuming `f` refers to a function), the latter is a function call.

The "II" part in IIFE means "immediately invoked", i.e. you don't just have a function expression, you immediately call it by putting `()` after it.

```
var getCode = function() {
  apiCode = '0]Eal(eh&2';    

  return function() {
    return apiCode;
  };
}
```

This assigns `function() { apiCode = '0]Eal(eh&2'; return function() { return apiCode; }; }` to `getCode`.

```
var getCode = (function() {
  apiCode = '0]Eal(eh&2';    

  return function() {
    return apiCode;
  };
}();
```

Here we have `function () { ... }()`, so this immediately calls the outer function and assigns the return value to `getCode`, which is `function() { return apiCode; }`.

Perhaps a simpler example:

```
var x = function () { return 42; };    // x is a function that, when called, returns 42
var y = function () { return 42; }();  // y is 42
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, an `IIFE` executes the function once and puts the returning value to the variable.

E.g;

```js
let res = (function sum(){
return 1+2;
})();
console.log(res);
```

On the other hand, `function expression` just holds a reference to the function and needs to be invoked.
E.g.;

```js
    let res = function sum(){
    return 1+2;
    };
    console.log(res());
```